# matplotlib fill_between issues with y1 & y2 arguments?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I've a pandas dataframe and i'm trying to plot the data to make a bett

```
        wave       mean    median        mad
0    4050.32  -0.016182 -0.011940   0.008885
1    4208.98   0.023707  0.007189   0.032585
2    4374.94  -0.001321 -0.001196   0.000378
3    4379.74   0.002778  0.003380   0.004685
4    4398.01  -0.002974 -0.004633   0.011037
```

I'm trying to plot column `wave` against column `mad` and i want to put the `MAD` of colulmn `mad` as the error. Instead if putting the error bars, i want to use the `fill_between` from `matplotlib` but i don't understand what should give as an input to `y1 & y2`in this

```
plt.fill_between(x['wave'], y1= ???, y2= ???, color='k',alpha=.5)
```

I've tried this? Is it correct?

```
plt.figure()
x=pd.concat([wave,mean,median,mad],axis=1,keys['wave','mean','median','mad'])
x=x[np.abs(x['mad']-x['mad'].mean()) <= (2*x['mad'].mad())]
plt.plot(x['wave'],x['mean'],'<')
plt.fill_between(x['wave'], y1=+x['mad'].mad(), y2=-x['mad'].mad(), color='k',alpha=.5)
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x['wave'],x['mean'])
plt.plot(x['wave'], intercept + slope*x['wave'], 'r', label='fitted line')
plt.show()
```

But it doesn't seems to be working because that's what i'm getting.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrP9y.png)

How can i do this?

Comment: What is `.mad()`  supposed to do?

Comment: it will calculate the the mad of complete column.  So instead of putting  an errorbar for each point i want  to put the MAD of column 'mad' as the error by using the fill_between.

Comment: Ok, so you really want the mad of the mad then, sorry, that was confusing. Anyways, what is the problem? "it doesn't seems to be working" is so general it could mean anything.

Comment: Thta's the problem sir, it's so general but still it ain't working.

Comment: What does "it ain't working" mean? Does the computer explode?

Comment: I've added the plot have a look over it. That's what i'm getting.

Comment: I see. You need to sort your data ascendingly by `x['wave']`.